# Flutter Web how get image path or do operation on image after picked from desktop with image_picker_for_web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, imagepicker

I am using these packages :
image_picker: ^0.6.7+14
image_picker_for_web: ^0.1.0+2

after a picture picked from desktop I want to send it's path to a class to do some operations on it. on android I don't have any problems but in web version the path is something like : blob:localhost:231/xdfsdfsdfsdsfsf
without any mime type, image type, anything, and it's a bit useless.

```
ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
final imageFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
print(imageFile.path);
```

if there is no way to get path in web version, how can I use that blob and do operations I want on my image?

Comment: getting the path on the web is not possible.

Comment: @nitishk72 so you mean I can't do what I want to, in flutter web version for now?

Comment: As far as I know, you can not get the path of the file in the browser.  

If you use any other tool in the browser then also it's not possible. HTML, CSS, JavaScript nothing will help you here.

Comment: @nitishk72 do you know how can I use that blob image that returns from imagePicker?
can I make operations on it, like crop and send it to server?

Comment: of course, you can do that. whatever you are trying to achieve is possible and it can be done without the path also.

Comment: @nitishk72 would you please explain more and send me some code? thanks

Comment: sorry Mr. Hadi but I can't help you at this point. Trust me it's possible and if you try then definitely you will achieve soon. 
Thanks